# Is it possible that a linux syscall read(from a regular file) set errno EINTR?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, system-calls

I learned that `syscall write` to a `regular file` does not generate `EINTR` error([Why can't a write to disk be interrupted by signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040913/why-cant-a-write-to-disk-be-interrupted-by-signal))

What about a `read syscall` in `linux`? Do "slow" devices include `disk device`?

(if SA_INTERRUPT is set)

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry. I've corrected my question

Comment: It is always better to write code that is able to handle an error return value with `errno == EINTR`, even if this error will not occur under certain preconditions. Can you guarantee that the file is a regular file? This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35224048/10622916